# table-header-group and table-footer-group in a Div

Tags: html, html-table

Is there a way of using table-header-group and table-footer-group in a div instead of in a thead or tfoot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) it is allowd to use `display: table-header-group` when the parent (the element containing the div) is displayed as a table or inline-table. So something like this should be allowed

```
<table>
  <div style="display: table-header-group;">header group</div>
</table>
```

If the parent is not a table, then it should be inserted, according to point 4 on the [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) page.

The big problem is, whether all (major) browsers support this. Especially IE(6) is known for not supporting most kinds of display types.

Answer (score 4):

According to W3C you cannot use a  element as a direct child node inside of a `<table>`. http://w3schools.com/html5/tag_table.asp. This article states that a `<table>` may contain:

- tr
- td
- th
- caption
- col
- colgroup
- thead
- tfoot
- tbody

what you could do if you want to avoid using a table is:

```
<div style="display:table;">
  <div style="display:table-header-group;">header group</div>
</div>
```

This solution however, is only possible in HTML5.